# Flat module and finite intersection of submodules

Tags: commutative-algebra, flatness

Let $R$ be an integral domain, $F$ be a flat $R$-module, and $A$ and $B$ are two $R$-submodules of $Q$, where $Q$ is the quotient field of $R$. How can we show that $F\otimes (A \cap B) = (F\otimes A) \cap (F\otimes B)$?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If $A, B$ are submodules of $Q$ (it is not important that $Q$ is the fraction field of $R$) we have an inclusion $0\to Q/A\cap B\to Q/A\oplus Q/B$. Tensoring with $F$, using flatness, we have $0\to F\otimes Q/A\cap B\to F\otimes (Q/A\oplus Q/B)$ to be exact. Now, one easily checks that $F\otimes Q/A\cap B=F\otimes Q/F\otimes (A\cap B)$ and similarly, $F\otimes Q/A=F\otimes Q/F\otimes A$ and same for $B$. Rest should be clear.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the exact sequence $0\to A\cap B\to Q\to Q/A\oplus Q/B$. Tensor this sequence with $F$ to get an exact sequence due to flatness, your statement follows from this resulting exact sequence.

Here we are just assuming that $A$, $B$ are $R$ submodules of the $R$ module $Q$.

ADDED LATER: after tensoring with $F$, the rightmost term will be $Q/A\otimes F\oplus Q/B\otimes F$. Now consider the exact sequence $0\to A\to Q\to Q/A\to 0$, tensoring this sequence with $F$ yields $Q/A\otimes F\cong (Q\otimes F)/(A\otimes F)$. Similarly for $Q/B\otimes F$. Putting this together we have the following exact sequence: $$0\to A\cap B\otimes F\to Q\otimes F\to (Q\otimes F)/(A\otimes F)\oplus (Q\otimes F)/(B\otimes F),$$ which yields your result.

Note: To conclude it will be necessary that you keep track of the maps, so that you can find the kernel of the map on the right of the last exact sequence.

Comment: The above sequence is not exact on the right in general.

Comment: oh yes, you are right, sorry that was in a hurry. I will make the change and add a few more details.